# 'Use of unassigned local variable' error inside foreach loop with yield return

Tags: c#, yield-return

Below method compiles fine.

```
string DoSomething(int x) {
    string s;
    if(x < 0)
        s = "-";
    else if(x > 0)
        s = "+";
    else
        return "0";

    return DoAnotherThing(s);
}
```

But when I write same code within a `foreach` loop and use `yield return` instead of `return` I get `Use of unassigned local variable 's'` compile error.

```
// Causes compile error
IEnumerable<string> DoSomethingWithList(IEnumerable<int> xList) {
    foreach(var x in xList) {
        string s;

        if(x < 0)
            s = "-";
        else if(x > 0)
            s = "+";
        else
            yield return "0";

        // COMPILE ERROR: Use of unassigned local variable 's'
        yield return DoAnotherThing(s);
    }
}
```

For me, it is so obvious `s` is assigned when code reached that line. What may be the cause for this error, may it be a compiler bug?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This isn't a compiler bug. (There are very few of those around, really, so the chances of hitting one are small.) It's a quite simple bug in your code.

When the value of `x` is zero, your code enters the `else` block and yields `"0"`. When the next value is requested, the method continues and executes this line:

```
yield return DoAnotherThing(s);
```

... and you have not assigned any value to `s` at this point.

Comment: Thanks! That was something I did not know. Then, `yield return "0"; continue;` may fix my problem. But for the sake of readability I will find some other neat solution :)

Answer (score 3):

If `x` is equal to zero, `s` is never assigned. So you're passing an unassigned variable to `DoAnotherThing()`.

It's possible you want `yield break` in the else clause. Keep in mind that `yield return` does not return the same way as a normal function. It returns one item, but allows you to keep iterating. `yield break` stops iterating.